# how to create categorized webforms in drupal?

Tags: webforms

I want to create a multiple Forms in my site . so i am going with the webform module , i want webforms in such a categorized as display below ,

general inquiry  Forms

1. general feedback
2. general inquiry
3. Training request

Product  Inquiry Forms

1. Product 1 Inquiry
2. Product 2 Inquiry
3. Product 3 Inquiry
4. Product 4 Inquiry

   Service
5. Service Request
6. service Feedback
7. online parts request

   In this  general inquiry  Forms is like  a category and genaral feedback and inquiry is webforms. so how can i create that for prodcut inquiry and service categorized multiple form.

and there are many fields are common in that different form , so if i have to create different fields for different form or can i use one field in a multiple time in different forms.

Thanks,
vipul.

Answer (score 1):

With Views, you can group the results by the value of a field, so create a field for your Forms and then group by that. You will have to get creative (custom templates) to get the numbering, if that's important to you.

As for sharing fields between Forms, I don't know of an easy way to do that.